# Creating eslint custom rule to prevent 'NOT NULL' in SQL files

Tags: eslint, rules

I want to have a custom Eslint rule so that all the files under:

apps/database/migrations/*.sql

Do not have the following string `NOT NULL`. So for example, if a file is:

```
CREATE TABLE users {
  id NOT NULL
}
```

I want the rule to trigger.

I've no clue on how the ESLINT code analyzer would treat those SQL files, so I don't know where to start. Is that even possible, or it just works with .js files?

Answer (score 0):

To create Eslint rules worked on based on the parser. Let's assume if I want to write a rule for javascript their many parsers.

For SQL queries we need to use `sql-parse`. Each parser returns a specific AST and we can write conditions on top of that as per need.

Here is some open-source example: https://github.com/uphold/eslint-plugin-sql-template/blob/master/rules/no-unsafe-query.js